# Problem with accuracy and loss in deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, nlp, mathematical-optimization

I'm doing a self-study, learning to use deep learning for text classification.
I use the Bi-LSTM model and I tried to change parameters with 10 epochs to compare results.

The dataset contains approximately 35k rows, in total with more than 1,200k tokenized words. The dataset is labeled with 2 classes. After tuning the parameters, I did the stratified 10-fold cross validation, 8 scenarios gave normal results, but these 2 scenarios happened.

-- The fist result:
it seems like the model couldn't improve the accuracy. What might be the cause of problem?
[image]
[image]

-- the second result:
this might be worse than the first one, in this case, does it has something to do with the network’s weights update?
[image]
[image]

Correct me if I'm worng.
I'm quite new with deep learning techniques and not familiar with some technical terms, so excuse me if I used some wrong words.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

ok so you have enough data to train the model so I guess the model structure might result into something like this, try the model structure shown below and tell if this works:

```
input = Input layer 
model = Embedding layer
model =  Bidirectional layer
model = TimeDistributed
model = Flatten
model = Dense(100,activation='relu')(model)
output = Dense(3,activation='softmax')(model)
model = Model(input,output)
```

and then try to compile the model using Adam optimizer , and at the output use softmax activation which can I guess have some drastic impact if not used before

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I forgot to tell that  the dataset contains approximately 35k rows, in total with more than 1,200k tokenized words. I did the stratified 10-fold cross validation, 8 scenarios gave normal results, but these 2 scenarios happened.

Comment: hi I have edited the above answer please check it if it helps